# $| f_n |^p - | f |^p - | f_n-f |^p$ converges in distribution sense if $f_k$ converges almost everywhere and weakly to $f$?

Tags: reference-request, limits-and-convergence, calculus-of-variations

Let $1<p<\infty$ and $f_n$ be a sequence in $L^p(S^1)$ that converges weakly to some $f$. Here $S^1$ is the circle so we are dealing with periodic functions.

Let us see if $| f_n |^p - | f |^p - | f_n-f |^p$ converges to zero in distribution sense. This means that for every smooth function $\phi$ on $S^1$, $\int_{S^1}(| f_n |^p - | f |^p - | f_n-f |^p)\phi$ goes to $0$.

Of course this is false because we can think of $f_k(x)=1+sin(kx)$.

Now, what if we impose another condition that $f_k$ converges almost everywhere to $f$?
I encountered this issue while studying calculus of variations and it seems much deeper than I thought. Is there any theorem or result for this problem?

Comment: For $p=4$, with $f=1$, $| f_n |^p - | f |^p - | f_n-f |^p$ does not converge to $0$ in the distribution sense.

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide answer for the case where $f_k$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere as well as weakly? It seems like a very deep result...

Comment: I would if I knew the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_{n,\epsilon}$ be the set where $|f|<\epsilon|f_n|$. Now split the integral of $(|f_n|^p-|f|^p-|f_n-f|^p)\phi$ into an integral over $A_{n,\epsilon}$ and an integral over its complement. Since the $L^p$ norm of $f_n$ is bounded, the former part is bounded by a constant times $\epsilon$. The latter part converges to zero as $n\to\infty$ by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Are you perhaps the author of a PDE textbook???

Comment: Yes, I am the author of a PDE text.

Comment: Thank you for your powerful answer; and I am taking a PDE class using yours as one of the textbooks. Thank you for the nice textbook too :)

Comment: @Michael Renardy Very nice solution. Then it works also for $p=1$.

Comment: @Michael Renardy    Could you help me with this question as well if possible?  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355072/dirichlet-to-neumann-operator-on-the-circle-and-pde-af-alpha-ef

Answer (score 3):

Here's a partial answer: For $p$ an even integer, it's true.  Maybe someone else can see how to handle the other cases.

In this case, the desired integral can be written as
$$\left(-\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} (-1)^{k} \binom{p}{k} \int_{S^1} f_n^k f^{p-k} \phi\right) - \int_{S^1} f^p \phi.$$

Recall the following fact: for any $q>1$, if $g_n$ is bounded in $L^q$ and converges almost everywhere to $g$, then it converges to $g$ weakly in $L^q$. For the proof, see Bogachev's *Measure Theory*, Proposition 4.7.12, or work it as a nice exercise.

Note that since $f_n$ converges weakly in $L^p$, by the uniform boundedness principle it is bounded in $L^p$ norm.

Now for any $1 \le k < p$, $f_n^k$ is bounded in $L^{p/k}$ norm.  Therefore it converges, almost everywhere and  weakly in $L^{p/k}$, to $f^k$.  Moreover, $f^{p-k} \phi$ is in $L^{p/(p-k)}$, where $p/(p-k)$ is the conjugate exponent of $p/k$. So we have $\int_{S^1} f_n^k f^{p-k}\phi \to \int_{S^1} f^p \phi$, and the desired integral converges to
$$ \left(-\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} (-1)^{k} \binom{p}{k} - 1\right) \int_{S^1} f^p \phi$$ 
and the expression in parentheses is $-(1-1)^p = 0$.